# How to analyse a trace file with .ttl extension generated by a Data logger for example PM-200?

Tags: python, ttl

I had a file with '.ttl' extension, I want to parse it but when I opened the file on notepad it show some data in good tag format(like html) but When I scroll down it difficult to analyze since it is filled with some unknown special character.
I am looking for a tool or code which can decode this file and to extract the key and it's related values.[tag:.ttl file] [tag:PM-200 data logger] [tag:python to decode]

The content of this files are below, please take a note this file is huge in size cannot post it, hence a small chunk is provided below

```
JiJiO½O½TýTýZ3Z3_H_H A  ! \»0Ðñ  A   ^»0Ðñ     A  ^»0Ðñ HA  a»0Ðñ   33   }ú  €†Ý`    üþýS|¸ƒ       ÿ             §ò¦= ü   Ž   ê}    €ÿŸ     Êy‡|     ¥ð?     £   lƒÿª    -      €€z €   €   €€z             o         ŒÕ       ™cÿßÿ÷ßÿþ÷ßÿþ÷ÿýÿþýÿÿÿ  û    „Òÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿ¿ÿÿÿÿÿ      7   VB$ÀûÿÿŸû?      ³   ÿòÿÿ?ßáŸÿÉÿý þ  A   S»0Ðñ  A  »0Ðñ ¦   É‹HA  x»0Ðñ   33   }ú  €†Ý`    üÿýS|¸ƒ       ÿ             §ò¦= ü   Ž   ê}    €ÿŸ     Êy‡|     ¥ð?     £   lƒÿª    -      €€z €   €   €€z             o         ŒÕ       ™cÿßÿ÷ßÿþ÷ßÿþ÷ÿýÿþýÿÿÿ  û    „Òÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿ¿ÿÿÿÿÿ      7   VB$ÀûÿÿŸû?      ³   ÿòÿÿ?ßáŸÿÉÿý þ  A  ! {»0Ðñ  A   }»0Ðñ     A  }»0Ðñ  A + b-»0Ðñ \   îí A  [»0Ðñ  A  ! †»0Ðñ  A  ! ‰»0Ðñ  A  ! Œ»0Ðñ l A 
 Œ»0Ðñ   33   Z}ú  €†Ý`     þýS|¸ƒ      åÿ             Z§ò¦=  -Ò  Ó        ÿÿàÿ        A  ! »0Ðñ  A   “»0Ðñ     A  “»0Ðñ  A   ˜»0Ðñ     A  ˜»0Ðñ  A   Ÿ»0Ðñ     A  Ÿ»0Ðñ l A  ¢»0Ðñ   33   Z}ú  €†Ý`     þýS|¸ƒ      åÿ             Z§ò¦=  -Ò  Ó        ÿÿàÿ        A  ! ª»0Ðñ  A  ! °»0Ðñ  A  ! ²»0Ðñ  A  q»0Ðñ \   ^l A  ¸»0Ðñ   33   Z}ú  €†Ý`     þýS|¸ƒ      åÿ             Z§ò¦=  -Ò  Ó        ÿÿàÿ       l A  Í»0Ðñ   33   Z}ú  €†Ý`     þýS|¸ƒ      åÿ             Z§ò¦=  -Ò  Ó        ÿÿàÿ        A * 0¼º0Ðñ æÿ      A  ±¥0Ðñ ;    ÿQ€! A  s¥0Ðñ   à  9 qà A 
 å»0Ðñ   33  }ú Î   †Ý`    ”ÿýS|¸ƒ        Îÿ            §ó§0 ”àò€b¼’ÝW’@ICS ÌRÌRÏbÏbÒ£Ò£ÖÖÙ™Ù™ÝRÝRá4á4å<å<éhéhí½í½ò.ò.öÈöÈûzûz N N>>
@
@aa’’ÔÔ$$$…$…)è)è/Y/Y4Ä4Ä:9:9?¢?¢E
E
JiJiO½O½TýTýZ3Z3_H_H A " d#¥0Ðñ ÿÿ      A  Ä»0Ðñ Œ    A   ý»0Ðñ P    A  Ä»0Ðñ \   Ý A   ¼0Ðñ     A   
¼0Ðñ     A + b¼»0Ðñ \   îä A   ¼0Ðñ (    A   ¼0Ðñ     A  ! ¼0Ðñ  A   !¼0Ðñ     A  !¼0Ðñ  A  ! >¼0Ðñ  A   @¼0Ðñ     A  @¼0Ðñ  A  ÿ»0Ðñ \   ^ A  ! I¼0Ðñ  A  ! L¼0Ðñ  A  ! O¼0Ðñ  A  ! R¼0Ðñ  A   V¼0Ðñ     A  V¼0Ðñ  A   [¼0Ðñ     A  [¼0Ðñ  A   b¼0Ðñ     A  5¼0Ðñ µ    A  b¼0Ðñ  A 
 p¼0Ðñ kTÝ A  ! m¼0Ðñ  A  ! s¼0Ðñ  A  ! u¼0Ðñ  A  [¼0Ðñ  A + bJ¼0Ðñ \   îä A   À¼0Ðñ P    A   Ê¼0Ðñ     A  ¼0Ðñ \   ^ A   Ð¼0Ðñ     A   Ø¼0Ðñ (    A   Þ¼0Ðñ     A  ! â¼0Ðñ  A   ä¼0Ðñ     A  ä¼0Ðñ  A  Ä¼0Ðñ Œ   : A    ×¼0Ðñ  "Ÿý}    €ÿŸ     åEI             @2L A  ! ½0Ðñ  A   ½0Ðñ     A  ½0Ðñ  A  ! ½0Ðñ  A * 0ü»0Ðñ æÿ      A  ! ½0Ðñ  A  ! ½0Ðñ  A  ! ½0Ðñ  A   ½0Ðñ     A  ½0Ðñ  A   ½0Ðñ     A  ½0Ðñ  A   %½0Ðñ     A  %½0Ðñ  A + bÙ¼0Ðñ \   îæ A  ! 0½0Ðñ : A    
½0Ðñ 8#«ßràÿçÿçÿçÿ øÿß×××çÿçÿçÿçÿ÷ÿ‰‰‰é  ^Ä A  ! 6½0Ðñ  A  ! 8½0Ðñ  A  ½0Ðñ \   ^: A    ?½0Ðñ   "_Ð eºÆê žþ       €@û      €ˆÓî A  [½0Ðñ  A   ƒ½0Ðñ P    A   ½0Ðñ     A   “½0Ðñ    : A    s½0Ðñ  
"™ŸGàÿÿÿ; —{>šA
  78  d2         Ð A   ›½0Ðñ (    A   ¡½0Ðñ     A  ! ¥½0Ðñ  A   §½0Ðñ     A  §½0Ðñ  A + bg½0Ðñ \   îí A  ! Ä½0Ðñ  A   Æ½0Ðñ     A  Æ½0Ðñ  A  ! Ï½0Ðñ  A  ! Ò½0Ðñ  A  ! Õ½0Ðñ  A  ! Ø½0Ðñ  A   Ü½0Ðñ     A  Ü½0Ðñ  A   á½0Ðñ     A  á½0Ðñ  A   è½0Ðñ     A  è½0Ðñ  A  ©½0Ðñ \   ^ A  Ä½0Ðñ Œ    A  ! ó½0Ðñ  A  ! ù½0Ðñ  A  ! û½0Ðñ : A    Û½0Ðñ  #–ÍøÿÿÿÿOˆÿÿ  ÿÇ1 (-àÿçÿçÿç     `¼¦¡ A  p¸½0Ðñ  Tù: A    ¾0Ðñ  
#ë_      xøÿÿÿþ‚ùÿ      ðï     ˜*Û$ A + bö½0Ðñ \   îä A   F¾0Ðñ P    A   P¾0Ðñ     A * 0<½0Ðñ æÿ      A   V¾0Ðñ     A   ^¾0Ðñ (    A   [¾0Ðñ  A   d¾0Ðñ     A  ! h¾0Ðñ  A   j¾0Ðñ     A  j¾0Ðñ : A    D¾0Ðñ  #lŸúû€ÿÿÿ£ïGßÿ?øß  þþþþþþþþ        ‹HÝ A ˜ hR¾0Ðñ  A  7¾0Ðñ \   ^ A  ! ‡¾0Ðñ  A   ‰¾0Ðñ     A  ‰¾0Ðñ  A  ! ’¾0Ðñ  A  ! •¾0Ðñ  A  ! ˜¾0Ðñ  A  ! ›¾0Ðñ  A   Ÿ¾0Ðñ     A  Ÿ¾0Ðñ  A   ¤¾0Ðñ     A  ¤¾0Ðñ  A  w¾0Ðñ _    A   «¾0Ðñ     A  «¾0Ðñ  A  ! ¶¾0Ðñ  A  ¾0Ðñ â   O A  ! ¼¾0Ðñ  A  ! ¾¾0Ðñ : A    ¬¾0Ðñ  #ŸŸ            dð?                §•7 A + b„¾0Ðñ \   îä A   Õ¾0Ðñ  A  Ä¾0Ðñ Œ    A  Ò¾0Ðñ    A  Å¾0Ðñ \   ^: A    á¾0Ðñ  #âßv„ÿª                           €ze A  r ë¾0Ðñ $   A     ¿0Ðñ P    A   ¿0Ðñ     A   ¿0Ðñ     A   !¿0Ðñ (    A   '¿0Ðñ     A  ! +¿0Ðñ  A   -¿0Ðñ     A  -¿0Ðñ : A    ¿0Ðñ  #e  €€z €   €   €€z         €,K¢ A  ! J¿0Ðñ  A   L¿0Ðñ     A  L¿0Ðñ  A  ! U¿0Ðñ  A  ! X¿0Ðñ  A  ! [¿0Ðñ  A  ! ^¿0Ðñ  A   b¿0Ðñ     A   [¿0Ðñ  A  b¿0Ðñ  A   g¿0Ðñ     A  g¿0Ðñ  A + b¿0Ðñ \   îæ A   n¿0Ðñ     A  n¿0Ðñ : A    I¿0Ðñ  #_·àÿa¬?   ðÿ÷ÿ      £öÿÿÿ d      GÆ
 A  ! y¿0Ðñ  A  d¿0Ðñ  A  ! ¿0Ðñ  A  ! ¿0Ðñ  A * 0|¾0Ðñ æÿ      A  S¿0Ðñ \   ^ A   Ì¿0Ðñ P    A   Ö¿0Ðñ     A   Ü¿0Ðñ     A   ä¿0Ðñ )    A   ê¿0Ðñ     A  ! î¿0Ðñ  A  Ä¿0Ðñ Œ    A   ð¿0Ðñ     A  ð¿0Ðñ  A + b¡¿0Ðñ \   îí A  ! 
À0Ðñ  A   À0Ðñ     A  À0Ðñ  A  ! À0Ðñ  A  ! À0Ðñ  A  ! À0Ðñ  A  ! !À0Ðñ  A  á¿0Ðñ \   ^ A   %À0Ðñ     A  %À0Ðñ  A   *À0Ðñ     A  *À0Ðñ  A   1À0Ðñ     A  1À0Ðñ  A  ! <À0Ðñ à A † <À0Ðñ   33  }ú Î   †Ý`    ”ÿýS|¸ƒ        Îÿ            §ó§0 ”—O€b¼“ÝW’`ICS dPdPi5i5n n rrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrr A  ! BÀ0Ðñ : A    À0Ðñ  "í_Ñ         ŒÕ                   €†Æ A  ! DÀ0Ðñ  A  ñ¿0Ðñ a   ±Ò"œ A ˆ TÀ0Ðñ   33   }ú   †Ý`    PÿýS|¸ƒ       ÿ             §î¦= PòA    @                                                                 A Ï  PÀ0Ðñ œ A ˆ jÀ0Ðñ   33   }ú   †Ý`    PÿýS|¸ƒ       ÿ             §î¦= PòA    @                                                                : A    NÀ0Ðñ  "”ß^dÿßÿ÷ßÿþ÷ßÿþ÷ÿýÿþýÿÿÿ         €51’ A , j7À0Ðñ \   ïà A 
 }À0Ðñ   33  }ú Î   †Ý`    ”ÿýS|¸ƒ        Îÿ            §ó§0 ”—O€b¼“ÝW’`ICS dPdPi5i5n n rrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrr
```

Please let me know, if you have any solution.
I tried to look for the solution but did not find. But just to inform that this is not RDF file which can be used by Turtle to decode.

Answer (score 0):

You need to ask TTTech for the description of the dataformat of .ttl logfiles.
The file consist of several header, definition and logging sections. No way to parse it without the knowledge of the structure.
The easiest way to parse the file is with existing tools from TTTech or CANoe from Vector but for proper display you need the datadescription from the OEMs.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).